# NSStatusBarButton template image wrong color

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsstatusitem

I'm try to migrate my status bar app to use an `NSStatusBarButton` on Yosemite instead of a custom view, but I'm having trouble getting the template image to work.

I'm configuring the `NSStatusItem` like this:

```
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
self.statusItem.button.imagePosition = NSImageLeft;
self.statusItem.button.target = self;
self.statusItem.button.action = @selector(clickButton:);
```

then I'm setting the image and title later on like so,

```
self.statusItem.button.title = [self statusItemTitleForLocation:location];

NSImage *image = [self statusItemImageForLocation:location];
[image setTemplate:YES];
self.statusItem.button.image = image;
```

The images that I'm using are PNG files with only black and transparent colors.

It seems to be pretty random how it will display. Sometimes it displays black like it's supposed to and switching to dark mode will make it turn white. But when turning dark mode back off, the text and image will stay white. Other times the app will launch (with dark mode turned off) and the text and image will be white and stay white, even after toggling dark mode on then off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you get this to happen in a small test app? I haven't seen this happen in any status item apps / test apps.

Comment: @Taylor just tried that and it seems to work as expected. I guess I have some more investigating to do.

Comment: I've actually seen this with Spotlight, of all things! Try simply restarting your app.

Comment: @seaturtle This is quite old and I'm not sure if my exact issue is even still present in the latest macOS, but I remember that restarting the app had no effect on this in my case.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Killing Spotlight has always worked for me, maybe something else is going wrong. But you're doing it exactly the way I did it, except for the fact that you're using a button...could that be the problem?